# How to toggle(Open/Close) `T` or `N` Panel in 3D view Using Python

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, interface, add-on

I want to hide or show blender T and N panel using Python.
From This[image]
To This[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle), which will toggle `N`- or `T`- panel of whatever `area` operator was called.

```py
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="space_data.show_region_ui")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

If you run this script and call the operator in `Text_Editor` It will open this side panel.[image]

So if you want to open/close `N Panel` of view3d from other areas you need to **override context**. It is a way to fool blender thinking that operator was called in different area.

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.toggle_properties"
    bl_label = "Toggle N Panel"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context):
        for area in context.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                with context.temp_override(area=area):
                    bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="space_data.show_region_ui")
                break
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # Test call
    bpy.ops.wm.toggle_properties()
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```py
import bpy

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        #copy context
        context_copy = context.copy()
        #loop over current areas
        for area in context.screen.areas:
            #Check if there is 3d view area
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                #If yes then override context
                context_copy['area'] = area
        
        #Now pass our custom context.
        #When calling any bpy.ops operator it takes context in which it was called
        #but you can override that.
        #look here for Offical documetation : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context
        bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(context_copy,data_path="space_data.show_region_ui")
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Now when you run script and call operator from text editor, it will open `n panel` of 3d view

**Where does the `data_path` comes from?**

What I do is go to *Edit > Preferences> Keymap*, change search type to `Key-Binding` and type key which is used in Blender to open/close whatever panel you want. Here I am searching for `Tools` or `Toolbar` or `T panel` in viewport. It can be open using `T` so I searched for it and this yields to the following the operator call:

[image]

`bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="space_data.show_region_toolbar")`